# How was the Old Norse Edda likely formatted?

Tags: norse

If you look at version of it online, it's all broken down into verses and stanzas, all numbered. But I wonder if this is how it was originally written down, or if the verses weren't ever marked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Elder or Poetic Edda is known entirely from the ***[Codex Regius](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codex_Regius)***, a 13th-century collection of Norse poems written on 45 vellum pages.  The general form of the text is what we would today call a "wall of text":

[image: Codex Regius]

(Source: Wikimedia Commons, Public Domain asserted)

([Here's a website](http://www.germanicmythology.com/works/CODEXREGIUS.html) that shows pictures of the individual pages a little more closely.)

The poems' textual representation of grouped and numbered lines is done by modern scholars. However this does **not** imply that the poems have no structure. Their stanzas and lines are naturally deduced from the inherent [alliterative verse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alliterative_verse) structure of the words themselves.

Before the poems were written down, of course, they were recited from memory.

Comment: Excellent! Do you perhaps know if in the Codex Regius the "speakers" were announced before each stanza, like "John said: ..." and "Jane said: ....". E.g. [Þórr kvað:](https://heimskringla.no/wiki/Hymiskvi%C3%B0a).

Comment: @LancePollard https://www.voluspa.org/poeticedda.htm

Comment: that is one of a million examples of supposedly "ancient" texts, but they have tons of modern formatting. is that formatting present in the original original?

Comment: @LancePollard The picture in my answer shows the original original directly....

Comment: I don't see the speaker or the colon in the picture.

Comment: @LancePollard I bought a side-by-side transcription/translation in dead tree form and things like  "Þórr kvað" did appear in the verse, but only because it was part of the verse.....